# Adding multiple editor on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I want each click of link add, adding CKEditor. My code adding CKEditor for first clicked. What can done it for all click?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/M2pEb/1/)** : http://jsfiddle.net/M2pEb/1/

Html:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.2/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a class="add" href="#"><span class="icon-caret-right"></span>Add</a>
<div class="000" style="width: 400px;height: 100px;">
</div>
```

Js:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.add', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.000').append('<textarea class="ckeditor" name="description_ser" id="des"></textarea>');
$('.ckeditor').each(function(){
    CKEDITOR.replace( $(this).attr('id') );
});
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't have multiple elements of the same id (`des` in your case) in the document. try something like:

```
i=1;
$(document).on('click', 'a.add', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.000').append('<textarea class="ckeditor" name="description_ser" id="des-'+i+'"></textarea>');
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'des-'+i );
  i++;
})
```